# how to target array of post to make one line of code instead of multiple?

Tags: php, forms, post, phpmailer

As you can see I would need to create multiple lines for each item in the form, How can I make one line(to target the entire post array I guess is what I need to do?) to include the entire $_POST my current method is below .

```
$name = trim(preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', ' ',    urldecode(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($_POST['name']))))));
$email = trim(preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', ' ', urldecode(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($_POST['email']))))));
$phone = trim(preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', ' ', urldecode(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($_POST['phone']))))));
$make = trim(preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', ' ', urldecode(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($_POST['make']))))));
$model = trim(preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', ' ', urldecode(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($_POST['model']))))));
$year = trim(preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', ' ', urldecode(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($_POST['year']))))));
$vin = trim(preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', ' ', urldecode(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($_POST['vin']))))));
$insurance_company = trim(preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', ' ', urldecode(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($_POST['insurance_company']))))));
$message = trim(preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', ' ', urldecode(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($_POST['message']))))));
$IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] ?: gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);



 I use this to make  all the fields into one variable 
$combineall = $name . $email . $phone . $make . $model . $year . $vin . $insurance_company . $message . $message . $IP ;
```

and

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
Once the button is pressed cleans the all the fields in the post array. 
$combineall = trim(preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', ' ', urldecode(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($combineall))))));
```

something like this is what im looking for but this does not work any idea how to fix it???

```
$_POST = trim(preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', ' ', urldecode(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($_POST))))));
```

Comment: Either loop over the contents of $_POST yourself, or use `array_walk`.

Comment: Btw., what are all those operations you are compounding there, supposed to be good for? What _exactly_ are you trying to sanitize your data for here?

Comment: Also unclear, why are applying this to all the individual values first, then combine them into one - and then apply the same operations again to the result? What’s the point, did you think any of the characters you removed from the individual values, would “sneak back in” somehow?

Comment: It prevents someone from using form to upload files to a server to use them to send spam by using $&{] characters and their html alternatives with curl

Comment: better safe than sorry

Answer (score 0):

Create a field list and iterate over it.

```php
$fields = ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'make', 'model', 'year', 'vin', 'insurance_company', 'message'];
$combineAll = '';
foreach($fields as $field) {
    $combineAll .= trim(preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', ' ',    urldecode(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($_POST[$field] ?? ''))))));
}
$combineAll .= $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] ?: gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

### Update

To iterate over all fields independent of key names you can do so as below. But take note, that you have no control of not existing keys or order!

```php
foreach($_POST as $field) {
    $combineAll .= trim(preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', ' ',    urldecode(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($_POST[$field] ?? ''))))));
}
$combineAll .= $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] ?: gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

Comment: im looking for something simple like this but i can't make it work.

Something like this is what im looking for but this does not work any idea how to fix it???

    $_POST = trim(preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', ' ', urldecode(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($_POST))))));

Comment: I can't follow what you are doing there. Make yourself familiar how arrays work and not to overwrite superglobals.

Comment: I am guessing you want no field list. Updated answer.

Comment: im not trying to overwrite it im trying to target it when submit butting is set to run through the entire array and do the actions of trim,strip ect

Comment: Look at your last comment. You assigned a string to `$_POST`. What about my updated answer? Did it help you?